# Pass parameter to Ajax safe way

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to pass the id to the controller (ASP.NET MVC 5) and get the result from the controller. I have the following code:

```
function LoadBook(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Book/GetBookById' + id,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error: " + err.responseText);
        }
    })
}
```

Is it safe to do **url: '/Book/GetBookById' + id**? And if it doesn't safe, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to URL-encode your parameter.

Comment: If you're looking for a RESTful way to do this, your URL should look like `/Book/[id]` or `/Book/GetBookById/[id]` (the second way seems redundant to me).  Non-RESTful you could do /Book/GetBookById?id=[id]. 
That said, the VS tools could scaffold this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prescribed way to do this is:

```
public JsonResult GetBookById(int id)
{
   // do your getting here
   var yourdata = MyDataAccessClass.getBookById(id);
   return new Json(yourdata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Your AJAX url would then be:

```
function LoadBook(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Book/GetBookById/' + id,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err.responseText);
    }
})
}
```

This is the "safe" and standard way to make calls in Microsoft's MVC.

Comment: You still need to escape the parameter.

Comment: Only if it's not an integer. In my example it is, so no escaping is needed. Of course, it's not clear what the data type is in the OP's code. :-)

Comment: @richb01 this is extractly what I did. Thank you!
Thank you too SLaks, I didn't know about the encoding parameter to make it safer. But everyone can decode it right? Because I see the encoding table on W3C, how encoding will make the parameter safer?

Comment: @richb01: Just because the parameter is declared as an integer doesn't mean that `id` in the JS is always an integer.  It could have a query string or `../some other action` and be used to attack things.

Comment: @UçanKartal: Learn about URL encoding.

Comment: @SLaks: I see your point. There should be *some* validation on the client side. And URL encoding is an important concept. That said, a non-integer would cause the code I wrote to throw an exception (type mismatch or something similar.) Either way, encoding does go a long way toward code safety.

Comment: @richb01: No.  If `id` is `1?secretParam=blah` or `../DeleteBook/24`, no error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
 encodeURIComponent(Id)
```